# valgrind - different results with hellgrind vs leak-check

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I have some strange behaviour that I do not understand. The code is a bit complex so I would refrain from posting it here and instead describe the behaviour and **hope that somebody, knowing how valgrind works, has an idea that I can pursue** despite this little information.

### Background:

I am developing some additional functionality for an open-source, c/c++ based agent-based modelling platform [fork @ my github](https://github.com/FrederikSchaff/Lsd). Compilation is fine. Everything seems to work as it should so far based on my validation with test-programs. Also, valgrind does not report any errors of relevance. But, reproducability (which is crucial) is strange.

Within the framework one defines a model file (initialisation of a simulation run, basically). Based on this file, one should be able to reproduce the exact same output (and platform independent). In a way this works: If I start the simulation environment (GUI version), load the file and run it, it produces the same result each time. Also, using the command-line version, I get the same results each time.

But, if, from a running instance of the simulation environment, I run the same model more than once, then the strange behavior occurs - sometimes...

### Compiler options used:

```
CC=g++
GLOBAL_CC=-march=native -std=gnu++14
SSWITCH_CC=-fnon-call-exceptions -Og -ggdb3 -Wall
```

### The set-up:

I run the compiled file and, internally to the program compiled, a fixed simulation set-up three times. Now, it should produce the exact same results each time, which I check by printing random numbers at different stages.

### The strange behaviour:

#### Option #1:

When I run the program in valgrind using the options:

`valgrind --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=high --show-reachable=yes`

I do not get the same results internally

#### Report from Option 1:

```
Finished processing sim1
==6206==
==6206== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6206==     in use at exit: 43 bytes in 1 blocks
==6206==   total heap usage: 4,124,309 allocs, 4,124,308 frees, 888,390,511 bytes allocated
==6206==
==6206== 43 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==6206==    at 0x4C2DDCF: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==6206==    by 0x5BE7FB2: getcwd (getcwd.c:84)
==6206==    by 0x143391: lsdmain(int, char**) (lsdmain.cpp:203)
==6206==    by 0x10C37D: main (main_gnuwin.cpp:29)
==6206==
==6206== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6206==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6206==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6206==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6206==    still reachable: 43 bytes in 1 blocks
==6206==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6206==
==6206== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6206== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

#### Option #2

However, when I use the following option instead:

`valgrind --tool=helgrind`

I do get the same results each time with the command line version. Interestingly, the first results with option #1 are the same as the results with option #2.

I would be happy for any suggestions. And, I am not a trained computer scientist... I am using  and mt1937 (reinitialised each time) - but the initial random numbers between the simulations are the same, so I do not think the error resides here. Although later within the run the random numbers change in Option #1 (this is my test, besides the time the simulation needs to find an equilibrium).

Comment: `SSWITCH_CC=-fnon-call-exceptions -Og -ggdb3 -Wall` always go full error mode. Add `-Wextra -pedantic` if you can.

Comment: thx. I removed the -fnon-call-exceptions just to make sure (but the exception handling would still throw, only with a different kind of message) and added -Wextra -pedantic. Some minor warnings resulted. They are not the reason, though.

Comment: To have some more ideas, you might run with more tools e.g. try --tool=none. After that, you might enable some tracing in your application and/or use valgrind+gdb+vgdb to debug under memcheck and debug a native run, and investigate at what point they differ of behaviour.

Comment: Ok, with --tool=none it runs as it should, but with e.g. --tool=memcheck it doesn't. I do not get any exceptions, though... Any idea what could make the difference?

If I run the program without gdb / valgrind, it also works as it should... - with -O3 and also with the gdb options.  Should I simply be fine with this expected behaviour and ignore the unexpected behaviour in valgrind-memcheck mode?

Comment: Normally, the behaviour of your program should not change when run under valgrind, and should also not change depending on the tool used. Which version of valgrind are you using ? If using the most recent one does not fix this, then it is worth investigating which piece of code changes of behaviour when run under memcheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could find the issue: At two points in the program I sort a temporary vector with pairs of distance values and pointers of objects located on a 2d space:

`std::sort( vector.begin(),vector.end() ); // vector of std::pairs<double, pointer>`

The solution, obviously, is to only sort by the first item of the pair:

`std::sort( vector.begin(),vector.end(), [](auto const &A, auto const &B ){return A.first < B.first; } );`

Some remarks on why I did not find this issue directly:

- When I implemented this sort, I intended to make it "stable". The pointers of the objects are kind of unique, thus in different subsets the ordering would be the same and also independently of how I add the items to the set.
- I did not consider that pointer values are (not precisely, but in effect) random numbers outside of my control.
- I did not see this, because somehow the OS (or whatever) always assigns the same pointer values between different calls of the program (I suggest there is a "virtual" space that is always initialized again). Because of this, I did not suggest that pointers were the issue.
- Curiously, when I ran the program with Valgrind and `--tool=helgrind` option, the issue did not persist. One suggestion I got (offline) was that memcheck preinitialises the memory with a given pattern, this would have been an answer if uninitialised variables had been the cause. As it seems, helgrind also controls the memory in different scopes, providing for each of my subsequent simulations a "fresh" virtual memory such that my pointer sorting was stable in the repeated loop.

I hope this helps somebody if he or she runs into the same problems. Thanks for all the suggestions!